# What is the formula for ARIMA(1,0,0) with regressor model in R via auto.arima process?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I have run an ARIMAX model in R which outputs ARIMA(1,0,0) as the best model.

I get the coefficients by model$coef which returns coefficients for ar1, intercept & 3 covariates - x1, x2, x3.

Forecasts of the above model are obtained by - predict(model, n.ahead=1, newxreg = test_data[,covariates])$pred

When I try to do this manually via the formula -

forecast_y(t) = coeff_intercept + coeff_ar1 * y(t-1) + coeff_x1 * x1(t) + coeff_x2 * x2(t) + coeff_x3 * x3(t),

the model forecast & the above forecast_y(t) are in completely different ranges.

I am wondering if auto.arima fits a separate model formula for the above process. I have tried to see the documentation, but the model structure is not mentioned anywhere.

Can anyone help me with the above?

Comment: Please check this one: https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html

Comment: See also https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/